# Tensor product sanity check

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I've been trying to understand what the elements in a module tensor product "are", using the tensor product of vector spaces as a model, but my intuition gets confused when the ring we're tensoring over isn't simply a field anymore. Can someone verify the following statements I've made about them?

1. Let $R = k[x, y]$ ($k$ is some field). Then in $R \otimes_R R$, we have $$1 \otimes xy = x \otimes y = y \otimes x = xy \otimes 1$$
2. On the other hand, let $I$ be the ideal in $R$ generated by $x$ and $y$ (i.e., polynomials with constant term 0). Then in $I \otimes_R I$, we have
   $$x \otimes y = y \otimes x \neq 1 \otimes xy = xy \otimes 1$$
3. In $R \otimes_R I$, we have
   $$x \otimes y = y \otimes x = 1 \otimes xy \neq xy \otimes 1$$

Comment: Where do you get the idea that $x\otimes y=y\otimes x$? That isn't true in most cases in your second and third example.

Comment: Part 1 is correct. Part 2 is false: The first equality sign is incorrect, and the stuff after the $\neq$ sign just doesn't make sense ($1 \notin I$). In part 3, the right hand side doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I see now why 2 and 3 are correct/nonsensical, but I don't see why they make sense in 1. What is the module relation between $x \otimes y$ and $y \otimes x$?

Comment: In 1 you can pull scalars out freely. $x\otimes y=xy\otimes 1=y\otimes x$.